# NiFi Truststore issue

Tags: apache-nifi

The truststore defined in nifi.properties file is not working for our NiFi 1.19.1 app and using JDK11

Error Message from logs:

2023-03-01 11:31:52,165 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-21] org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: ldapserver.com:3269; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldapserver.com:3269 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:190)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:79)
at org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider.authenticate(LdapProvider.java:276)
at org.apache.nifi.web.security.spring.LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean$1.authenticate(LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.apache.nifi.web.api.AccessResource.createAccessToken(AccessResource.java:416)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

appreciate the help!

Comment: Error just saying `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` - it's normal when certificate not found.

Comment: Sounds like the certificate wasnt found in the path. I would say, you could add a new certificate to the truststore or put the certificate in the provided path to Nifi, or change the path that NIFI has to the new location. Then try again